# If I have a UITableViewController class, where do I initialize its instance variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

It works if I put it in `viewDidLoad` but I can't imagine that's the best place to do it. I tried putting it here:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // HERE
    }
    return self;
}
```

But that didn't work. Where should I put it?

In this example I'm talking about creating the NSMutableArray (alloc and initing it) for this class.

Comment: How are you creating instances of this class? Are you doing this in a storyboard/nib or from code?

Comment: What instance variables? You need to provide some useful information if you want any good help.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify in the question. Say I have an NSMutableArray I need to alloc init, where do I do it? And this class is the initial view controller, so it's created automatically.

Comment: Consider using lazy initialization at getters, that'll be a universal solution independent from initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with a lazy-loading technique as A-Live suggests in the comments, such that your array will be initialized when you actually need it.  The idea is that in a property getter, you first check to see if your array was initialized.  If not, initialize then return it.

**Example**

> Note: This is a crude and untested example, and you may need to make
>   the necessary changes depending on whether or not you use ARC.

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *_myArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *myArray;
-(void)doSomething;
@end
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
@interface MyViewController()
-(NSArray *)fetchArrayData;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize myArray = _myArray;

#pragma mark - Property Getter
-(NSArray *)myArray
{
    if (_myArray==nil)
        _myArray = [[self fetchArrayData] retain];
    return _myArray;
}
#pragma mark - Cleanup
-(void)dealloc
{
    [_myArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark - Instance Methods
-(void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"myArray: %@", self.myArray);
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods
-(NSArray *)fetchArrayData
{
    NSArray *arrayData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples", @"Oranges", nil];
    return arrayData;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 initialization methods:

```
- (id)init
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

It all dependes on how you're instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your instance variables in `initWithStyle:` if you create your controller programmaticaly or in `initWithCoder:`/`awakeFromNib` if it's loaded from nib/storyboard.